# How to run a celery client without running the flask app

Tags: flask, celery, worker

I'm trying to understand how to use Celery following this [example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/). Basically, I create the flask app and then I run Celery(app,...). Then to run flask app "flask run -A app ..." and to run the celery client "celery -A app worker -l INFO". The thing is that the celery client also runs the flask app, and the initialization functions. I would expect that the flask app just runs normally whereas the celery client just waits for tasks to arrive. I don't understand why it works this way. Isn't the point of celery to run separatly from the flask app? How can I run the celery client without running the flask app? What am I not understanding?